# Why the nᵗʰ root of the determinant of a matrix equals to the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, orthonormal

I was doing some algebra exercise and I noticed that to normalize an orthogonal matrix $M_{n \times n}$, I can just divide the matrix using the nᵗʰ root of the absolute value of the determinant.

I know that the determinant can be defined as how much the size of the area, volume,[...] created with the column vectors increases compared to the one created with canonical vectors, and I also know that to normalize the vector I can divide it by the norm of vectors of the matrix, so I am asking myself why it works when I use the the nᵗʰ root of the determinant in the place of the norm to get the normalized form of the matrix?

Comment: What exactly is the "it" that works?  You can divide the matrix by the $n$'th root of the absolute value of the determinant, and the result is... what?  And what do you do if the determinant happens to be $0$?

Comment: about the first and second question I just fixed it, and if the determinant is 0 than it means the vectorial space is compressed in a lower dimension one, and you will only normalize the matrix if the vectorial space doens't change dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which number you should divide by depends on what you want, i.e. what exactly it means for a matrix to be "normalized" in your context.

If you want a matrix whose norm is $1$, divide by the matrix by its norm.  If you want a matrix whose determinant has magnitude $1$, divide the matrix by the $n$th root of its determinant.

Comment: so in the context of an orthogonal matrix, where all column vectors are perpendicular and have the same length, the fact that dividing the matrix by the nth root of its determinant to normalize it only works because in the context of an orthonormal matrix I need both the determinant and the lengths of the column vectors to be 1?

Comment: Now I finally understand what you mean by "normalize an orthogonal matrix": you have a matrix (whose columns are for some reason orthogonal and of the same length), and you would like to divide the matrix by some number so that the result is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. so that the resulting matrix has orthogonal *and* unit-length columns.  In the future, please try to make your questions clearer.

Comment: Also, note that in the standard usage, an "orthogonal matrix" is a matrix whose columns are orthonormal.  A matrix whose columns are only orthogonal does not have a standard name.  In other words, there is no such thing as an "orthonormal matrix".

Comment: But yes: the fact that you can accomplish your goal by dividing by the $n$th root of the determinant all comes down to a property of orthogonal matrices (i.e. matrices whose columns are orthonormal), which is that every orthogonal matrix has a determinant with magnitude $1$.